# orders between two dates mysql magento

Tags: php, mysql, date, magento, time

I want to get all orders between two dates

```
$order_collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array(
                'from' => $FromDate,
                'to' => $ToDate,
                'date' => true,
                ));
```

if my from date is 2016-10-23  its not getting orders generated at 23/10/2016 00:00:01 to 23/10/2016 00:59:59. Any help please

Comment: Do you pass the same format dates?

Comment: Using a date picker and converting dates with strtotime                           $FromDate = date('Y-m-d i:s', strtotime($fromDate));
      $ToDate = date('Y-m-d i:s', strtotime($toDate));

Comment: Try to pass to `Mage::getModel ` converted dates in the same format as they are in the database. (I don't know if it is `DATE` or `DATETIME` in you table)

Comment: Thanks for replying its timestamp

Comment: Your convert `$ToDate = date('Y-m-d i:s', strtotime($toDate))` has `i:s` which means `minutes:seconds` ... so if `$toDate = 23/10/2016 00:59:59` then `$ToDate` will be converted to `2015-10-23 59:59` .... You can try executing such query manually to see if it works correctly with such data and debug it.

Comment: Thank you very much this gives me all orders of 23-10-2016                                             'from' => '2016-10-22 23:00:00', 'to' => '2016-10-24 00:00:00',

Answer (score 1):

you can get it with below code
note: check whether you have placed orders between two dates with the status completed

```
$Datefrom = '2016-10-10'; /* from date  */
$Dateto = '2016-10-25';   /* to date */

$Orderfrom = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($Datefrom));
$Orderto = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($Dateto));

$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
                         ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at',  array('from'=>$Orderfrom, 'to'=>$Orderto))
                         ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE));

foreach($orders as $order){
     print_r($order);
}
```